# Summation arithmetic distributing the summation sign

Tags: arithmetic

Assuming that $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i}{n}$, I have the following expression that I'm trying to simplify:

$\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + n\bar{x}^2$

$ = \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i^2 - 2\bar{x}x_i + \bar{x}^2) + n\bar{x}^2$

$ = \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i^2) - 2n\bar{x}\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + n\bar{x}^2 + n\bar{x}^2$

$ = \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i^2) - 2(\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i)^2 + \frac{2(\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i)^2}{n}$

However, the solution is

$ = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2$?

How did  $-2(\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i)^2 + \frac{2(\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i)^2}{n} = 0$?

Comment: You incorrectly equate $\sum 2\overline x x_i$ with $2n\overline x\sum x_i$.  (the $n$ shouldn't be there).

Comment: So what's the correct expression then? $2\bar{x}\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$? I thought we're summing $\bar{x}$ $n$ times?

Comment: Same as you wrote, but without the $n$.  The $2\overline x$ is just a constant...it simply factors out of the sum.

Comment: Clear now?  if $\lambda$ is a constant then $\sum \lambda x_i=\lambda \sum x_i$.  That's just the distributive law for addition.  You handle the last term correctly, as $\sum \overline x=\overline x\sum 1=n\overline x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lulu commented, your mistake was made at the second equal sign. It should be:
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2\bar x \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + n\bar{x}^2 + n\bar{x}^2 
= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -2\bar{x}(n\bar{x}) + 2n\bar{x}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2.$$